Is it possible to use Logcat without Android Studio?
I'm attempting to investigate Android crashes that occur while using my Samsung phone to control a drone, so Android Studio is unavailable to me during run-time. Is it possible for me to use Logcat during run-time, or does Logcat depend on Android Studio?
In the end, I really like Logcat for a number of reasons, but I can't seem to find much about its use outside Android Studio. Thoughts?
